# Showing 4 records in a portal from same table

Tags: filemaker

I have a table that contains students' results. These results are generally broken into four types: term1, term2, term3 and term4. So over a year, a student may have up to four records in that table containing his results.

I want to create a layout that contain a portal that will show all the 4 records in a single portal row. Is there any way to do this? Or any workaround?

The reason why I do not want to display the records as four rows in the portal is because there are different subjects and will not be right if each subject occupy four rows and there are many subjects a student may take.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to approach this, both of which would require a relationship from your **Results** table occurrence to another table occurrence based on Results, let's call it **Results~SameStudentID**.  (The matching field would the foreign key to the Student table, FK_StudentID = FK_StudentID.)

1. Create 4 calculation fields in your Results table: Result_1, Result_2, Result_n, etc.  The formula to use for each of the calculation (starting from the context of the **Results** table occurrence) would be:

   ```
   GetNthRecord ( Results~SameStudentID::Result ; n )
   ```

   Then, simply include the 4 "Result_n" fields in your portal
2. Create just one field, Results_1_4, with the following formula:

   ```
   Substitute ( List ( Results~SameStudentID::Result ) ; ¶ ; "    " )
   ```